# bulk delete apps in iDevice

Tags: ios, applications

I have a habit to download the latest apps gone free, however This results in many unused apps. (Lots of space gone!)

Deleting the apps the casual way, (tap'n'hold, delete) works, but takes too long for the confirmation to come up.

Is there any way I can just select multiple apps and click on delete? I don't generally care for the remove from game center as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend plugging into your computer and deleting your apps, much faster there

Comment: However you still do this one by one - and the answer here should include how to do this

Comment: I have heard of this idea, however using iTunes keeps freezing up. Any alternatives? (And yes how to please)

Comment: Have a look at https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?l=en&mt=12